# What is the complexity of this for loop, for (int j = 1; j < i; j *= 2)?

Tags: time-complexity

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
     //statement
   }
}
Answer: O(N)
```

I want to know what is the time complexity if the inner loop and the outer loop are reversed ,`O(n)`, `O(nlogn)` or `O(logn)`?

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i ++) {
   for (int j = 1; j < i; j *= 2) {
     //statement
   }
}
Answer: ?
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, the inner loop will execute for every value of n thus we need to sum logarithmic values.

Let's assume our base is 2.

```
log2(1) + log2(2) + log2(3) ... + log2(n-1)
= log2((n-1)!)
```

So the complexity would be O(log2((n-1)!)) which is the factorial of `n-1` in log 2 base.

And if you omit 2 it is `O(log((n-1)!))`

Turns out you can simplify further using [Stirling's approximation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) and come with the answer `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: The inner loop is executed log2(n) times, because j is multiplied by 2 in each step.

Comment: `O(log((n-1)!))` can (and should) be simplified to `O(n logn)`.

Comment: Your notation for factorials is incorrect, and a sum of terms is never a factorial: a factorial is a *product* of terms! I don’t know who upvoted this answer, since it’s simply wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph A sum of logarithms is the logarithm of the product, so it's correct to get a factorial (although it can be simplified further using Stirling's approximation).

Comment: @interjay Oh, I hadn’t noticed that the product was *inside* the log. Yeah, that would then indeed be correct but it’s also confusing here without the intermediate step that rewrites the sum of logs as the log of a product (and the notation is still wrong).